# How specify the identity seed for a property in the CodeFluent model?

Tags: codefluent

All the key properties in my CodeFluent model are of type ulong and must be automatically incremented by the database, for example:

```
<cf:property name="Id" typeName="ulong" key="true" persistenceIdentity="true" cfps:hint="CLUSTERED" />
```

One specific key property must start with the value 10 instead of 1.
How can I specify this?

Another question: Do you have documentation about the cfps namespace?

Answer (score 1):

Using the latest version of CodeFluent Entities (>=836) you can set the identity seed and increment at property level:

```
<cf:property name="Id" typeName="int"
             cfps:identitySeed="10" 
             cfps:identityIncrement="2" 
             xmlns:cfps="http://www.softfluent.com/codefluent/producers.sqlserver/2005/1"/>
```